# Proper query MySQL Using WHERE ON INNER JOIN Proper order and syntax

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

Just trying to get into the use of Joins and figure out the best usage and formulation of query. Trying to get all pets for OWNER - Do I call the join with the comparisons?

```
SELECT *
FROM VISITOR
INNER JOIN OWNER ON VISITOR.OWNER_ID = 1
AND OWNER.ID = 1
```

Or, do I call the full join and add a WHERE statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM VISITOR
INNER JOIN OWNER ON VISITOR.OWNER_ID = OWNER.ID
WHERE VISITOR.OWNER_ID =1
```

Any explanation as to what would be the correct method would also be appreciated.
Thanks all : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying, it is typical to have your joins based on the table-to-table relationship fields.  IN ADDITION, you can add additional criteria at the respective level to further filter your final data set.  That said...

```
SELECT 
      *
   FROM 
      VISITOR V
         INNER JOIN OWNER Own
            ON V.OWNER_ID = Own.OWNER_ID
   WHERE
      V.OWNER_ID = 1
```

Ensure you have an index on the visitor table on the "owner_id" key to help in optimization...  Or, you could reverse it such as

```
SELECT 
      *
   FROM 
      OWNER Own
         JOIN VISITOR V
            ON Own.OWNER_ID = V.OWNER_ID
   WHERE
      Own.OWNER_ID = 1
```

Comment: @KDawg, sorry, yes you DO need the "ON" clause